# Deleting picture taken in QField

Tags: fields-attributes, qfield, delete, graphics

I'm using QField all day and one thing kept bothering me which is that I am unable to delete a picture I take within the app.

When I'm doing cartography, I like to take pictures so that I have a visual memory of the places I've been to.
I prepare my QField column to take photos (apart from other options) as:

- Text, 255 lengths, Widget type: attachment, relative path.

Taking the pictures works fine, but sometimes I take a blurry picture by accident or I - for whatever reason - want to delete a picture I've taken.

How do I do this?

I don't see a delete button anywhere.  I'm using the latest version of Qfield.

Comment: Try to report here https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues and who knows, this functionality can be implemented.

Comment: I had the same problem and I haven't found a way to delete a picture. However, if you  uncheck the box "«hyperlink» on the attachment widget" You will be able to see the picture in qfield and take a new one in its place.  https://qfield.org/docs/it/prepare/attributes-form.html